# sold an iphone 5s, buyer is saying I didn't wipe and needs my 4 digit passcode

Tags: iphone

Sold an iphone 5s on ebay, thought I had wiped it clean (still think I did).  99% certain.

Buyer is in Ukraine.  States he can't activate phone because there's a passcode still on it.  Is asking for $20 refund to get it done.

Scam?

I logged into icloud and it doesn't show up in my devices.  Does that mean it was wiped clean?  Or perhaps I never could see it using icloud (find-my-iphone)?

Comment: ozliftoff's answer notwithstanding, you can check Activation Lock status on https://www.icloud.com/activationlock/

Answer (score 2):

**He can wipe it without your passcode, provided it is not locked to your iCloud account, which by the sounds of it, it's not.**

This can be done by connecting the phone to iTunes and then putting it in recovery mode. Quoting from Apple website [page here.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306)

1. Connect device to iTunes.
2. Put in recovery mode: Press and hold the Sleep/Wake and Home buttons at the same time. Don't release when you see the Apple logo. Keep holding both buttons until you see the recovery mode screen.
3. When you see the option to Restore or Update, choose Restore.

iTunes will download software for the device. If it takes more than 15 minutes, your device will exit recovery mode and you'll need to repeat steps 2 and 3.

Once done, the device can be set up and used as normal.

Answer (score 2):

From [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201351):

> ### If you no longer have your iOS device
>
> 1. Ask the new owner to erase all content and settings using [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201351#above) steps.
> 2. If you're using iCloud and Find My iPhone on the device, sign in to iCloud.com or the Find My iPhone app on another device, select the device, and click Erase. After the device has been erased, click Remove from Account.
> 3. If you can't follow either of the above steps, change your Apple ID password. This won't remove personal information that's stored on your old device, but it will prevent the new owner from deleting your information from iCloud.
> 4. If you're switching to a non-Apple phone, deregister iMessage.
> 5. If you're using Apple Pay, you can remove your credit or debit cards at iCloud.com. Choose Settings to see which devices are using Apple Pay, then click the device. Next to Apple Pay, click Remove.

If you erase your device on Find my iPhone, [it's no longer activation locked](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph2701?locale=en_US).
I see no harm in sendings the passcode after erasing it, though I'd start using a different one myself.